# Depth First Recursion in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am updating this question with a dataset so that I can get more help on this (based on feedback). I am not asking folks to do my homework but would certainly appreciate any pointers.

I have the following code

```
>> start of code
# BOM data
library("dplyr")
library(igraph)

text1 <- ("
          matnr,comp
          FG1,SA1
          FG1,SA2
          SA1,SA3
          SA1,SA4
          SA1,SA5
          SA5,SA6
          FG2,SA1
          FG2,SA8
          SA8,SA9
          SA9,SA10
          SA9,SA11")

df1 <- read.table(textConnection(text1),  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, sep=",")
head(df1)
net <- graph_from_data_frame(df1)
net
neighbors_FG1 <- neighbors(net, v=c("FG1"), mode=c("out"))
neighbors_FG1

neighbors_FG2 <- neighbors(net, v=c("FG2"), mode=c("out"))
neighbors_FG2            

neighbors_SA1 <- neighbors(net, v=c("SA1"), mode=c("out"))
neighbors_SA1

>> end of code
```

I want to be able to produce a data frame like below. I would think that this will need some sort of recursion and I would like to get help with this. If you can even help me with how I can get to the output below, that will be great.

FG,level,material,Comp
FG1,1,FG1,SA1
FG1,1,FG1,SA2
FG1,2,SA1,SA3
FG1,2,SA1,SA4
FG1,2,SA1,SA5
FG1,3,SA5,SA6
FG2,1,FG2,SA1
FG2,1,FG2,SA8
FG2,2,SA8,SA9

Comment: Hello Experts. 
I just need to solve the problem. I do not need this to be recursion at all. Thanks,
Satish

Comment: Please provide a complete problem statement including input., all code and library statements. No one can run what is in the question other than you since this is all missing. See the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page regarding the use of `dput`.  Also if you indent the code by 4 spaces SO will format it for you.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this could help you (with dummy data `df`)

```
df <- data.frame(
  from = c("A", "A", "A", "B"),
  to = c("B", "C", "D", "C")
)
net <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
v <- vall <- "A"
while (length(unique(unlist(vall))) < vcount(net)) {
  p <- neighbors(net, v)
  vall <- c(vall, list(names(p)))
  v <- p
}
```

which gives

```
> vall
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "C" "D"
```

---

Or, you can use `dfs`

```
> dfs(net, "A")
$root
[1] 0

$neimode
[1] "out"

$order
+ 4/4 vertices, named, from 9d73ae8:
[1] A B C D

$order.out
NULL

$father
NULL

$dist
NULL
```

[image]